# Word: Replace automatic line breaks with carriage returns

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I have quite an unusual problem. I have a MS Word file (created by Adobe Acrobat, original was a PDF)) which contains multiple text boxes. The content of these text boxes needs to be parsed so I can import it into a database.
The text in the PDF document is formatted into 2 columns. Unfortunately the file conversion in Adobe Acrobat does not insert a carriage return after every line. As a result, when the DOCX is saved as a text file, the text gets messed up. The file conversion in Word, the "adding line ends" option, doesn't work for text boxes or text frames. Transform all text boxes in paragraph text messes up the text too. 
In my opinion is the best way to solve this a vba macro which recognises every automatic line end in any text box in the document and inserts a carriage return. However, I've tried to do this with the predefined bookmark "\line" but this doesn't seem to work in text boxes either. I keep getting an error "The object is removed", which does not occur if only paragraph text is selected (not in a text box).

```
Sub ChangeAutoLineBreaks()
Dim r As Word.Range

Set r = Selection.Range

Selection.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseStart
Do Until Selection.End > r.End
  Selection.Bookmarks("\Line").Select
  If Right(Selection, 1) = " " Then
      Selection.SetRange Selection.End - 1, Selection.End
      Selection.Delete
      Selection.Text = vbCr
      Selection.Bookmarks("\Line").Select
      Selection.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseStart
  End If
  Selection.MoveDown wdLine, 1, False
Loop

' reselect our original selection
r.Select
Set r = Nothing
End Sub
```

I've tried other file migration tools (pdf>docx or pdf>txt), but I got the best result if the file conversion is done using MS Word as a bypass.

Does anybody have any tips how I can get this to work for me in Word?

[Screenshot describing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMQvk.jpg)

[Link to the docx document](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AoqW6eRR1HilhBaaRDsbnwzIDCJf)

Thx!

Peter

Comment: can you include some screenshots

Comment: also i've found a good way to ask your question is to produce some concise example files demonstrating the problem, and then anybody trying to answer you can try to solve the problem for those files. So, that with screenshots and clearly showing what you want vs what you're getting.  Your question doesn't look bad, but that would make a better question and one more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Screenshots added! Thx!

Comment: most people aren't that familiar with that unusual option you are using in word to show carriage returns and spaces and tabs.   And while you have tabs, it's not really clear that those tabs are giving you columns, as I don't see clear columns of data in either of your pics probably 'cos as you say, the columns got messed up.   Are you able to link to an example PDF?  e.g. upload to http://ge.tt  then anybody can download your file (not necessarily with chrome), but e.g. with  firefox.

Comment: The tabs are in fact giving me the necessary columns for now, but if I get stuck here I could easily transform them to spaces to preserve the column format. However, I cannot provide the PDF file because this shows confidential information and I am not able to anonymize the text like I did in the other examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx Máté, it didn't brought the solution but helped me in the right direction. Actually and because it is tricky, it was a simple analysis of the behaviour of the selections when the task was performed manually. Your solution assumed there was only one automatic line end within a paragraph, but there were paragraphs using more than 2 lines. This is how I solved it.

```
    Dim aShape As Shape
Dim aParagraph As Paragraph

On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each aShape In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    If aShape.Type = msoTextBox Then
        For Each aParagraph In aShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs
            aParagraph.Range.Select
            Selection.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseStart
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
            Do Until Asc(Selection.Text) = 13
                Selection.InsertAfter vbCrLf
                Selection.MoveDown wdLine, 1
                Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
            Loop
        Next
    End If
Next aShape

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Word doesn't have an object to mark line ends within paragraphs, so it's really a tricky task.

As a workaround you can:

- place selection to the beginning of each paragraph
- move done one line (like pressing down arrow)
- move back one character and check whether it's a paragraph break

  - if not, then add it

Below code sample does this process for one paragraph, just need to loop through all the paragraphs in your text boxes (I've tested, it works with text boxes too).

```
    Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    Selection.MoveDown wdLine, 1
    Selection.MoveLeft wdCharacter, 1, True
    If Asc(Selection.Text) <> 13 Then
        Selection.InsertAfter Chr(13)
    End If
```